# Attachment with mailto in Animate CC

Tags: image, actionscript-3, sdk, attachment, mailto

I have been trying to add a visible image like a jpg or or other image with AS3 to an email. I am nearly done with an iOS Air SDK application but can't solve this. When the user submits a mailto, the address, cc, and body fill in with text from a form, this was easy. However getting an email to populate the body with an image has been impossible.

```
var OneEmailone:String ="";
var vetEmail:String ="";
var subEmail:String ="";
var bodEmail:String ="";

submitProt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fEmailClickone);
function fEmailClickone(event:MouseEvent):void

{
OneEmailone = customer_email.text;
vetEmail = rep_email.text;
subEmail = "PCV2d Results";
bodEmail = vet_email.te;

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:"+OneEmailone+"?cc="+vetEmail+"&subject="+subEmail+"&body="+bodEmail ), "_blank");
}
```

Comment: PS: Is this part a spelling mistake... `bodEmail = vet_email.te;`? Should it be `vet_email.text`?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is untested but the logic is that you **use HTML formatting to embed the image**.

Try a body like:

```
bodEmail = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> This is an AS3 email with a test image: <br> <img src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqIRQ.png\"> embedded image.</body></html>";
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it. No compiling errors but it shows up as plain text in the email. I tried to add .htmlText but seems like that is no longer valid.

Comment: **(1)** You need request headers that mention that the content type is `text/html`. **(2)** Are you able to use PHP as an option? It might be better to send your text to a PHP script that sends the email (with rich-text content format). **Mailto** might be too limited for this task.